# Filter with DAX in power BI

Tags: powerbi, report, powerquery

I am trying to filter with a DAX measure in power BI. I have a list of countries by in my DAX formula I want to return United Kingdom and France

```
Country
United Kingdom
France  
Germany
Turkey
South Africa
Ghana
Nigeria
Australia
New Zealand
Fiji
Solomon Islands
Canada
United States
India 
Mexico
Brazil
China
```

My DAX is

```
ListCountry = CALCULATE(MAX(Orders[Country]),FILTER(Orders,Orders[Country]="France" || Orders[Country] ="United Kingdom"))
```

When I test it it returned only `United Kingdom`
BUT what I want is display

```
United Kingdom
France
```

Comment: You can work with multiple value or list of values or table inside a measure, but the ultimate output has to be a one single value. I guess the issue is just partly explained here. If getting list of those 2 country is all you are looking for, you need to store the output in a custom table as @Andrey answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns only `United Kingdom`, because you are calculating the `MAX` value (`MAX(Orders[Country])`). In this case, the filter returns `France` and `United Kingdom`, and the later one is the maximum value. Otherwise the filter returns what you expect:

```
Table = FILTER(Orders, Orders[Country] = "France" || Orders[Country] = "United Kingdom")
```

[image]